# Is th32ProcessID used in CreateToolhelp32Snapshot a handle

Tags: windows, winapi

The question is mostly in the title. I am trying to write an example using this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) however when I run it with the ALL flag and the handle for a process I get a -1 returned instead of a valid handle to a snapshot and when calling GetLastError I get 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.)

My question is does the th32ProcessID referenced in the MSDN link refer to a normal process handle or is there a different way to get this process ID?

I don't have a great deal of code for this at the moment but what I do have is below:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot([In] SnapshotFlags dwFlags, [In] IntPtr th32ProcessID);

IntPtr Handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.All, ProcessHandle);

Console.WriteLine("ProcessHandle = {0}", ProcessHandle.ToString("X"));
uint flags = 0;
bool result = GetHandleInformation(ProcessHandle, out flags);
Console.WriteLine("Last error = {0} and handle is valid = {1}", WinErrors.GetLastWin32Error(), result);
Console.WriteLine((int)Handle);
```

Comment: th32ProcessID is not a handle, a process ID (PID) is a simple integer.  So the declaration is wrong, use `int`.  You'd use the .NET Process.Id property to get a valid PID.  Or 0 if enumerating processes is the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process *HANDLE* is not the same thing as a process *ID*. They are not interchangeable.

`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` takes a process ID. And that parameter is a `DWORD`, so you should be using `(u)int` (aka `(U)Int32`), not `IntPtr`.

`GetHandleInformation()` takes a process HANDLE.

Since you are passing the wrong type of parameter value to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, it is failing, returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and then `GetLastError()` is telling you that the specified process ID was not found.

You can get a process HANDLE from a process ID by using [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess).

You can get a process ID from a process HANDLE by using [`GetProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid).